# Explicit computation of Choi matrix for a qubit channel

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics, quantum-computation, quantum-information

I'm struggling with the explicit computation of the Choi matrix of a generic quantum channel ${\Phi}:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}^2$.

I know that I can write the channel in the Bloch representation as
${\Phi}(v_0 I+\mathbf{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma})=v_0I+(\mathbf{t}+T\mathbf{v})\cdot\vec{\sigma}$, with $\vec{\sigma}=(I,\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z)$ the vector formed by the basis of the real vector space of Hermitian $2\times2$ matrices $\mathcal{H}(2,\mathbb{C})$, given by the 3 Pauli matrices plus the identity.

I am interested in the case in which $\mathbf{t}$ is a generic translation vector $(t_1,t_2,t_3)$ and $T$ is diagonal $T=\text{diag}(\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3)$, i.e. the cases in which $\Phi$ can be represented by the $4\times4$ matrix
$$
\mathbb{T}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
t_1 & \mu_1 & 0 & 0\\
t_2 & 0 & \mu_2 & 0\\
t_3 & 0 & 0 & \mu_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Since the Choi matrix $\Lambda_\Phi$ of $\Phi$ is
$\Lambda_\Phi=\begin{pmatrix}\Phi(E_{11}) & \Phi(E_{12})\\ \Phi(E_{21}) & \Phi(E_{22})\end{pmatrix}$ (where each $E_{ij}$ is a $2\times2$ matrix with $1$ in the $(i,j)$-th position and $0$ elsewhere) in order to compute it I've been trying to use the definition of $\Phi$ above to calculate the four $\Phi(E_{ij})$s.

I wrote $E_{11}$ as a linear combination of the elements of the basis $\{ I,\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z \}$ and got $E_{11}=\frac{1}{2}I+\frac{1}{2}\sigma_z$ and so $$\Phi(E_{11})=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1+t_3+\mu_3 & t_1-it_2\\ t_1+it_2 & 1-t_3-\mu_3\end{pmatrix}.$$

Analogously $E_{22}=\frac{1}{2}I-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_z$ and so $$\Phi(E_{22})=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1+t_3-\mu_3 & t_1-it_2\\ t_1+it_2 & 1-t_3+\mu_3\end{pmatrix}.$$

So far everything is alright and in accordance with what I should get.

I have problems in the calculations of $\Phi(E_{12})$ and $\Phi(E_{21})$.

In a first attempt I did the same reasoning and got $E_{12}=\frac{1}{2}\sigma_x+\frac{i}{2}\sigma_y$ and so $\Phi(E_{12})=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}t_3 & t_1-it_2+\mu_1+\mu_2 \\ t_1+it_2+\mu_1-\mu_2 & -t_3\end{pmatrix}$.
But this is wrong because I know that I should get $\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0 & \mu_1+\mu_2 \\ \mu_1-\mu_2 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

I think that my mistake is the following: I cannot write $E_{12}$ as a linear combination of $\{I,\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z\}$ with complex coefficients, because $\mathcal{H}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is a real vector space.
But since the two matrices $E_{12}$ and $E_{21}$ are not Hermitian (they are not symmetric) it is not possible to write them as a linear combination $\{I,\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z\}$ with real coefficients, so I don't know how to proceed.

How can I compute $\Phi(E_{12})$ and $\Phi(E_{21})$?

Answer (score 1):

Your general argument is correct, and the mistake you made is keeping an identity component where there shouldn't be one. Indeed using ($\mathbb C$-)linearity of $\Phi$ your calculation yields
$$
\Phi(E_{12})=\frac{1}{2}\Phi(\sigma_x)+\frac{i}{2}\Phi(\sigma_y)
=\frac{\mu_1}{2}\sigma_x+\frac{i\mu_2}{2}\sigma_y
=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0& \mu_1+\mu_2 \\ \mu_1-\mu_2 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is exactly what it should be. I assume that you accidentally carried over the extra summand
$$
\frac12\begin{pmatrix} t_3&t_1-it_2\\t_1+it_2&-t_3 \end{pmatrix}=\Phi(I)
$$
from your calculations of $\Phi(E_{11})$, $\Phi(E_{22})$ to $\Phi(E_{12})$.

As for your second question: I am not aware of the existence of something like a Choi matrix for linear maps $\Phi$ on real symmetric matrices. Actually, I doubt that such a thing exists -- or if it does, it does not resemble the Choi matrix as we know it. Recall that the Choi matrix works as it does because it embeds an orthonormal basis of the domain of $\Phi$ into a larger matrix $C$ which is positive semi-definite. Now if the Choi matrix of $\Phi$ (that is, $(\Phi\otimes\operatorname{id})(C)$, resp. $(\operatorname{id}\otimes\Phi)(C)$) is positive semi-definite, then it can be diagonalized into pairwise orthogonal vectors. Partitioning these vectors and re-arranging them into $n\times n$ matrices yields the Kraus operators of $\Phi$ -- and the Kraus form is readily verified to always be completely positive. The two big problems I see are the following:

- As you pointed out an orthonormal basis of
  $
  \mathsf{Sym}_2:=\{A\in\mathbb R^{2\times 2}\,:\,A=A^T\}
  $ is given by
  $$
  \Big\{\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix},\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\Big\}\,,
  $$
  for short $\{E_0,E_x,E_z\}$. While the usual Choi-matrix is given by
  $$
  C=E_0\otimes E_0+E_x\otimes E_x+E_y\otimes E_y+E_z\otimes E_z=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\,,\tag{1}
  $$
  we do not have access to $E_y$. But getting rid of the $E_y\otimes E_y$ term yields
  $$
  E_0\otimes E_0+E_x\otimes E_x+E_z\otimes E_z=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&2\end{pmatrix}
  $$
  which is not positive semi-definite anymore. Making it positive semi-definite (while keeping the coefficients equal; this is important as we will see later on) leads to
  $$
  \frac12\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&1\\0&1&1&0\\0&1&1&0\\1&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=E_0\otimes E_0+E_x\otimes E_x
  $$
  meaning it does not capture the action of $\Phi$ on $E_z$; hence it cannot characterize complete positivity.
- Of course every symmetric matrix can be made positive by adding a "sufficient amount" of the identity to it. So we can always play with the weights in (1) to obtain a positive (but "asymmetric" in the weights) larger matrix
  $$
  C=2E_0\otimes E_0+E_x\otimes E_x+E_z\otimes E_z=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}3&0&0&1\\0&1&1&0\\0&1&1&0\\1&0&0&3\end{pmatrix}\,.
  $$
  By assumption we know that
  $$
  (\operatorname{id}\otimes\Phi)(C)=\frac12\begin{pmatrix} \Phi\begin{pmatrix}  3&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}&\Phi\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}\\\Phi\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}&\Phi\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&3 \end{pmatrix} \end{pmatrix}\geq 0
  $$
  so there exist pairwise orthogonal (not necessarily non-zero) vectors $g_1,\ldots,g_4\in\mathbb R^4$ such that $(\operatorname{id}\otimes\Phi)(C)=\sum_{i=1}^4g_ig_i^T$. The usual procedure turns these $g_i$ into Kraus matrices $K_i:=\operatorname{vec}^{-1}(g_i)$ where $\operatorname{vec}^{-1}$ is the inverse of [usual vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)). A straightforward computation shows that
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{i=1}^4K_i\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{pmatrix}K_i^T&=\frac{a}2\Phi\begin{pmatrix} 3&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}+\frac{b}2\Phi\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}+\frac{b}2\Phi\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}+\frac{c}2\Phi\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&3 \end{pmatrix}\\
  &=\Phi\begin{pmatrix}\frac32a+\frac12c&b\\b&\frac32a+\frac12c\end{pmatrix}
  \end{align*}
  for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$,
  meaning that not $\Phi$, but rather
  $$
  \Phi_S\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{pmatrix}:=\Phi\begin{pmatrix}\frac32a+\frac12c&b\\b&\frac12a+\frac32c\end{pmatrix}
  $$
  is completely positive. This may seem promising as all we have to do now is "un-mix" the diagonals -- but doing so is not (completely) positive, and applying a non-positive map to a positive one can yield anything. Indeed, $\Phi=\Phi_S\circ S^{-1}$ where
  $$
  S^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{pmatrix}:=\begin{pmatrix}\frac34(a-\frac13c)&b\\b&  \frac34(c-\frac13a)\end{pmatrix}\,,
  $$
  but $S^{-1}(E_{11})=\operatorname{diag}(\frac34,-\frac14)\not\geq 0$ so complete positive of $\Phi_S$ does not imply anything about $\Phi$.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! Now it is clear!

Now, I would like to do something similar for the real case, i.e. compute the Choi matrix for an operator acting on REAL $2$x$2$ symmetric matrices, i.e., $\Phi$ acting on $\rho=\frac{1}{2}(id_2+v_1\sigma_x+v_2\sigma_z)$. I can see that $\{I, \sigma_x, \sigma_z\}$ is a basis of the $3$-dimensional (real) vector space of real symmetric matrices and now $\mathbb{T}$ is $3\times 3$.

How can I write the Choi matrix of this operator? 
I can't write $E_{12}$ and $E_{21}$ as a linear combination of such a basis anymore, because they are not symmetric...

Comment: Interesting question, I edited my answer!

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpfulness! :)
So in your opinion there is no possibility to characterize the complete positivity of a map $\Phi$ acting as a channel on $\rho=\frac{1}{2}(id_2+v_1\sigma_x+v_2\sigma_z)$ via the Choi matrix? Then, how can we characterize it?

Comment: The keywords here are *operator systems* and *extension theorems*, see for example the first few pages in Chapter 6 of Paulsen's book "Completely Bounded Maps and Operator Algebras". Note that you cannot apply these results directly because they're formulated over complex matrices, but one can check that they also hold for real vector spaces and thus apply to your scenario.